# Using explode to get an array from an array changes nothing

Tags: php

I am getting input from the user in form of a comma delimited list and using this function to try and get an array from it.

```
public function getTags(){
    $posted = $this->input->post('le_tags');
    echo $posted .'<br/>';
    //sjhj,us9uiuo,uusooios,ooksokiod
    $new_array = explode(', ', $posted);
    //print_r($new_array);  
    foreach($new_array as $key=>$value){
    echo "i shall $value <br/>";
    //i shall sjhj,us9uiuo,uusooios,ooksokiod 
    }
    echo '<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">go back</a>';
    }
```

After running he new array into a foreach,nothing changes.

```
foreach($new_array as $key=>$value){
    echo "i shall $value <br/>";
    //produces i shall sjhj,us9uiuo,uusooios,ooksokiod 
    }
```

I want to use foreach to produce `i shall $value` and not `i shall with a comma seperated list`

Comment: You're trying to splt on comma and a space (`', '`) but your string looks like it's just commas (`','`) as a separator

Comment: Your string doesnt contains `', '` but `','`

Comment: I would never have guessed it right away.I thought php would ignore such minute details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
$new_array = explode(', ', $posted);
```

to

```
$new_array = explode(',', $posted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `','` rather than `', '` in the following line-

```
$new_array=explode(',', $posted);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure of spaces after `,` then you can use [preg-split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) like,

```
$posted='sjhj,us9uiuo,uusooios,ooksokiod';
// or use $posted='sjhj, us9uiuo, uusooios, ooksokiod';
$new_array=preg_split('/,\s*/i',$posted);
print_r($new_array);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => sjhj
    [1] => us9uiuo
    [2] => uusooios
    [3] => ooksokiod
)
```